# Asimov's short story about a little boy who finds a pistol with an AI. The AI enjoys being fired and teaches/convinces the boy to kill someone

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

Could be from an old issue of Asimov's Science Fiction. 80s to early 90s.

Comment: The years don't match but based on limited description Rocket Boy could still be potential match. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113549/

Comment: @Cheeseburger is "Asimov's short story" a short story by Asimov or in Asimov's?

Answer (score 5):

There's a recent story (2008) which won a hugo, ["The Ray-Gun: A Love Story"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ray-Gun:_A_Love_Story), about a sentient raygun found by a kid.

> The story is about an unpopular teenage boy who finds an alien ray gun
>   in the forest. Although he does not do much with the gun contemplating
>   its design or use, and handling the ray-gun when alone, gives his life
>   more direction and purpose. The story has some elements of "coming of
>   age" stories in that it follows an adolescent becoming an adult, PhD
>   student, and ultimately finding love. The ray-gun played a role in the
>   direction of his life in all these things. However, in the end the
>   ray-gun itself is abandoned as too dangerous or no longer needed.